# Constructor casting?

Tags: java

In the constructor, how would I represent the top and bottom `Diagram` parameters with a `char[][]`?
Casting doesn't work.

```
public CombineLeftRight​(Diagram left, Diagram right, int animationType)
```

A Constructor that initializes the `animationType` with the provided parameter value and initializes the board with the diagram resulting from calling `TwoDimArrayUtil.appendLeftRight()` on the boards associated with the left and right diagrams.

```
public static char[][] appendLeftRight(char[][] left, char[][] right) {
        int numRows = (left.length > right.length) ? left.length : right.length;
        int numCols = left[0].length + right[0].length;
        char[][] retArray = new char[numRows][numCols];
        TwoDimArrayUtil.copyArray(retArray, left, 0, 0);
        TwoDimArrayUtil.copyArray(retArray, right, 0, left[0].length);
        return retArray;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

```
public interface Diagram {
    /**
     * Returns a two-dimensional array of characters representing a diagram.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public char[][] getBoard();

    /**
     * Returns the next two-dimensional array of characters to display during an
     * animation.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public char[][] nextAnimationStep();

    /**
     * Number of rows associated with the diagram.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public int getNumberRows();

    /**
     * Number of columns associated with the diagram.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public int getNumberCols();
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that if your constructor is of this format:

```java
// Constructor
public CombineLeftRight​(Diagram left, Diagram right, int animationType){
   ...
}
```

Then you need to convert each `Diagram` into a 2D array of `char` - something along the lines of

```java
char[][] left2dArr = left.getBoard();
char[][] right2dArr = right.getBoard();
```

So that you can invoke the static method as you mentioned... like

```java
TwoDimArrayUtil.appendLeftRight(left2dArr, right2dArr);
// or simply
TwoDimArrayUtil.appendLeftRight(left.getBoard(), right.getBoard());
```

putting it all together (still guessing here as there is not enough code in your question to know for sure), your constructor could look like:

```java
// Constructor
public CombineLeftRight​(Diagram left, Diagram right, int animationType){
   ...
   TwoDimArrayUtil.appendLeftRight(left.getBoard(), right.getBoard());
   ...
}
```